# How to remove layer from textfield which was added programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added a layer (bottom border) to textfield with

```
- (void) addBorderToTextField:(UITextField *)textField borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth
{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    border.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [textField.layer addSublayer:border];
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Now I want to remove this border programmatically

I tried below but it crashes. Not sure if last object contained the desired object.

```
- (void) replaceBorderFromTextField:(UITextField *)textField borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth
{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    border.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    NSArray *subLayers = [textField.layer sublayers];
    CALayer *existingBorder = [subLayers objectAtIndex:[subLayers count] -1];
    [textField.layer replaceSublayer:existingBorder with:border];
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

How can I remove?

Comment: I have tried your code. Works just fine. Your bug msut be somewhere else. Please also post relevant code about how these two functions are called if you can.

Comment: I had two elements in subarrays...not sure which two...I used method provided by matt below and it works....I am sure in your test, you only had 1 element in subarrays hence it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple problem of identification. Fortunately, CALayer is KVC compliant for arbitrary keys. So you can use `setValue:forKey:` on your `border` layer, when you create it, to give it, say, a `@"name"` key whose value is `@"border"`. Later, when the time comes to remove it, you can identify the correct layer by cycling through the sublayers looking for the one (using `valueForKey:`) whose `@"name"` key is `@"border"`. (Actually it will probably be sufficient to find the layer whose `@"name"` key is anything other than `nil`!)